# Calculating intrinsic ratio for an image container with jQuery fails in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on adding lazy loading for images on a website, where the image height varies from panel to panel and images are scaled up by 50% on tablet and by 100% on mobile sized screens. Due to all the variation in image sizes, I'm calculating a bottom padding for the image containers on the fly and adding it inline for each container. This works fine in all other browsers expect IE11, which for some reason seems to be interpreting the image height wrong.

```
function calculateContainerPadding(image) {
    var mediaContainer = image.parent(".lazy-container");
    var bottomPadding = image.height() / mediaContainer.width() * 100;

    mediaContainer.css({
      "padding-bottom": bottomPadding + "%"
    });
}
```

I've created a fiddle of the bug:
http://jsfiddle.net/125gwu1e/29/embedded/result/

Would anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Not sure that I am following the issue you are reporting.   In both IE11 and Google Chrome it rendered the same for me.

Comment: Did you scroll down the whole page? When I load the page in IE11, I get a 100% bottom padding on most of the containers, which causes a lot of white spacing between the images. If you resize the browser, the paddings get corrected to what they should be to begin with, but it's on this first page load, that IE11 is having problems with. It's as if it sees the height of the images to be the same as their width.

Comment: It's not on every image container where it fails, and it seems to depend on browser size, on which containers the calculation goes wrong.